# Create multidimensional array from a loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array from some content I have in a database.

At the moment, I have this, which creates an array:

```
 $js_arr = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r->query)){
    $js_arr[] = $row['todo_content'];
}
```

Returning:

`Array ( [0] => first [1] => tester [2] => first item [3] => Hello!)`

However, I also need to grab the `$row['todo_id']`.

I've tried this, but it *only creates an array for the first row*:

```
 $js_arr = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r->query)){
    $js_arr['todo_content'] = $row['todo_content'];
    $js_arr['todo_id'] = $row['todo_id'];
}
```

Returning:

```
array(2) { ["todo_content"]=> string(3) "hey" ["todo_id"]=> string(2) "90" }
```

I'm still learning PHP so any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply nest the items you want inside an array:

```
$js_arr[] = [
    'todo_content' => $row['todo_content'],
    'todo_id'      => $row['todo_id']
];
```

The `$js_arr[]` part cannot ever be anything else, because any other syntax will not unconditionally add an element to the end of your multidimensional array.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this also works: `$js_arr[$i]['todo_content'] = $row['todo_content'];` Could you elaborate on the "not be anything else" part?

Comment: @tmyie: Another way to say "obviously you have to leave that alone, the solution will be elsewhere".

Answer (score 1):

Two good options:

If the `todo_id` is unique, let it be the key:

```
$js_arr[$row['todo_id']] = $row['todo_content'];
```

Or for a multi-dimensional array, needed if you have more than just `todo_content`:

```
$js_arr[] = array('todo_content' => $row['todo_content'], 'todo_id' => $row['todo_id']);
```

Comment: Would there be any advantages or disadvantages with using the todo_id as the key? (I'm js encoding this for jQuery)

Comment: If you need to access a row and know the id it would be easier to access that row:  js: `value = js_arr[5]["todo_content"]` php: `$value = $js_arr[5]["todo_content"]`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ID as the key:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r->query)){
    $js_arr[$row['todo_id']]['todo_content'] = $row['todo_content'];
}
```

Or - assuming you need everything that you get from the database:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r->query)){
    $js_arr[$row['todo_id']] = $row;
}
```

What you can replace with (no loop, but no ID's as keys):

```
$js_arr = mysqli_fetch_all($r->query);
```